# Credentials encryption in Apex

Tags: apex, encryption

In [this](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/calling-salesforce-web-services-using-apex) Apex documentation, it is advised to encrypt credentials and store them somewhere and then decrypt them in the class to perform for instance a login from API.

How am I supposed to do this ? Are there any Apex methods you can rely on ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce has Crypto class, which provides several OOTB encryption methods. It supports AES 128,192,256 bit key encryption.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

A sample code snippet will be

```
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Data to be encrypted');
Blob encrypted = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);

Blob decrypted = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, encrypted);
String decryptedString = decrypted.toString();
System.assertEquals('Data to be encrypted', decryptedString);
```

More detailed code:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AE3dIAG